# Access token on facebook is invalid - even after making it

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

I'm writing a facebook application in PHP with the facebook SDK.
The important parts in my code are:

```
    $facebook = new Facebook(array(
                'appId' => $ApplicationID,
                'secret' => $ApplicationSecret,
                'cookie' => true, // enable optional cookie support  
            ));
    $user = $facebook->getUser();

              $post = $facebook->api('/' . $user . '/feed', 'post', array(
              stuff
      ));
                $_SESSION['finish'] = false;
                $_SESSION['inside'] = 'yes';
                $_SESSION['uid'] = $user;
                $token = $facebook->getAccessToken();
                echo 'Access token: ' .$token;
                $_SESSION['friends'] = $facebook->api('/me/friends?access_token'.$token);
```

You can see I am `echo`ing the access token.
At first, I haven't added the `access_token` into the query - I just added it for checking.
The problem is that the last like (with the `/me/friends/`) throws an exception:

```
OAuthException: An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.
```

Although I did a login, and the `feed post` *did* work (I checked at my wall, it's there). Then, my `try catch` block handles the exception by redirecting to the login link, this way:

```
catch(Exception $e) {

            $login_url_params = array(
            'scope' => 'stuff',
            'fbconnect' => 1,
            'redirect_uri' => $ApplicationURL
        );
        $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl($login_url_params);

        //redirect to the login URL on facebook
        echo ("EXCPETION! " . $e . "<script> top.location.href='" . $login_url . "'</script>");
        exit();
        }
```

The code writing the exception is obviously only for debugging purposes.
Well, the first time I run the application a similar code is executed by a `if(!$user)` condition. Then it asks for my permission and I give it. Then, again, it says the access token is invalid (but does post to my wall).
Please note that I've compared the access_tokens, and even after removing the application and doing it all again - it stayed the same.

This is very awkward behavior and I fail to understand it. May anyone please shred some light on this? 
Edit: For some weird reason, the token doesn't change even after going to a different user. But the post on the wall is still made... (And the exception thrown when accessing the friends list)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For some weird reason, the token doesn't change even after going to a different user. But the post on the wall is still made... (And the exception thrown when accessing the friends list)

That sounds to me as if you don’t actually have a user currently logged in, so the SDK is just using your *app* access token, which is always the default token it will use before it receives another, more “specific” one.

What format does your access token have – does is look something like `your_app_id|your_app_secret` or `your_app_id|some_random_characters`? If it’s *starting* with your app id, it’s most definitively an *app* access token.

Comment: Yes, you are right. It is the app access token. Why isn't the application using the user access token? I *am* logged in to facebook, I did give the permissions... Note: It did work for a while now. It just stopped for no good reason.

Comment: Try removing your app from your user account settings under https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=applications, and then go through the login again – does it work afterwards?

Comment: Just did it - it doesn't change the behavior (it did ask for permissions first though...)

Comment: Redirecting to login only from a `catch` block is a little unorthodox IMHO … I’d say you should go to login if there is not Facebook user first.

Comment: I have, in my code `if(!$user) $facebook->getLoginUrl(...)` and a redirect... It stopped working only *today*.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I saw you checked off this answer, but based on your comments it doesn't seem to have fixed it. I am having the same issue.